# Removing edge weights from a Graph

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks

**Bug introduced in 8.0 and fixed in 12.2.**

---

How can I remove `EdgeWeight`s from a `Graph` without affecting any other properties of the graph?

Let's construct a graph with weights:

```
g = RandomGraph[{10, 20}, EdgeWeight -> ConstantArray[1, 20]]
```

Based on the documentation I would expect the following to return `Automatic` (the same thing it returns for a graph that has no edge weights):

```
PropertyValue[RemoveProperty[g, EdgeWeight], EdgeWeight]

(* ==> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} *)
```

However, it returns the weights that were originally set.

The following seems to work, but it removes other properties as well

```
PropertyValue[RemoveProperty[g], EdgeWeight]

(* ==> Automatic *)
```

Extracting the edges and vertices, then re-building the graph will discard other properties as well.  `Graph` objects are atomic, and they don't have a Mathematica-expression form, so trying to modify them at the expression level is not a possibility either.

**How can one then remove `EdgeWeight`s from a `Graph` without modifying any other properties of the `Graph`?**

**Update:** It turns out `WeightedGraphQ@RemoveProperty[g]` still returns `True`.  So even though the weight values are removed, the system still considers the graph to be weighted.

Comment: I think we are witnessing here one of the (probably many) consequences of the design decision which seems a departure from the general Mathematica design based on symbolic programming paradigm. I particularly like, and agree with [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363253/object-oriented-mathematica-programming/7379002#7379002) of @WReach, in this regard. I make this comment irrespective of whether or not your particular question has a (simple) solution.

Comment: @Leonid I completely agree.  BTW this question was triggered by some [bugs/crashes](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4621614#4621614) in `FindShortestPath`.  I think these types of crashes/problems would be less likely to occur if `Graph` weren't designed this way.  There are several [problems](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/RRsfrHCjwRM/discussion) which I think are related to the `Graph` data structure becoming corrupted internally.

Comment: Yes, I agree. And, I am not surprised. It is the impedance mismatch between mutability and idiomatic Mathematica, which makes the design particularly hard in cases when mutability is needed. Choosing an easy route just brings this impedance mismatch to the user. This is not an easy problem, of course.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has to be a bug. I think `Graph` never really associates `EdgeWeight` with corresponding edges.

Here is a simplified example.

```
g = Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {
                Property[1 <-> 2, EdgeWeight -> x],
                         1 <-> 3,
                Property[2 <-> 3, EdgeWeight -> y]
                }];

gNew = RemoveProperty[{g, 1 <-> 2}, EdgeWeight];
gNew2 = SetProperty[{g, 1 <-> 2}, EdgeWeight -> Missing["Nonexistent"]];


Outer[
            PropertyValue[{#1, #2}, EdgeWeight] &,
            {g, gNew, gNew2},
            {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3}
            ] // TableForm[#, 
                TableHeadings -> {{"g", "gNew", "gNew2"},
                 {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3}}] & // Quiet
```

[image: comparison of EdgeWeight list after removing]

Notice the `gNew` row, how `EdgeWeight`s are **mis-aligned** when the preceding one (i.e. `x`) deleted. And the 3rd column gives us a clue how `PropertyValue` extracts `EdgeWeight` -- that is, by `Part`.

I would definitely call this a bug.

---

The workaround I can come up with are two ways. The easy way is as I did for `gNew2` -- instead of removing it, replacing it with a placeholder. While the hard way is to permute the to-be-delete edge to the end of edge-list before performing the delete:

```
myRemoveEdgeWeight[g_, e_] :=
    Module[{vl = VertexList[g], el = EdgeList[g], pos, ewl, ew},
        pos = Position[el, e];
        el = Insert[Delete[el, pos], e, -1];
        ewl = PropertyValue[g, EdgeWeight];
        ew = Extract[ewl, pos][[1]];
        ewl = Insert[Delete[ewl, pos], ew, -1];
        Graph[vl, el, EdgeWeight -> ewl] //
            RemoveProperty[{#, e}, EdgeWeight] &
        ]

PropertyValue[{myRemoveEdgeWeight[g, 1 <-> 2], #}, EdgeWeight] & /@
 {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3}
```

> ```
> {{1, y}[[3]], 1, y}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

I should post this as a comment, but it is too long. Perhaps I'll delete it later.

There is also some nuisance with RandomGraph[]. Compare the following equivalent graphs:

```
n = 6;
g = CompleteGraph[n, EdgeWeight -> Range[n (n - 1)/2]]
WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[g] // MatrixForm
g1 = RandomGraph[{n, n (n - 1) /2}, EdgeWeight -> Range[n (n - 1)/2]]
WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[g1] // MatrixForm
```

**Edit**

Answering Szabolcs's comment:

```
n = 6;
g = CompleteGraph[n, EdgeWeight -> Range[n (n - 1)/2]];
w = WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[g] // MatrixForm;
g1 = RandomGraph[{n, n (n - 1) /2}, EdgeWeight -> Range[n (n - 1)/2]];
w1 = WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[g1] // MatrixForm;
Row[{w, w1}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is consistent if we take into account the different order of edges in `EdgeList[g]` and `EdgeList[g1]`.

Comment: What I mean is that the edge weights are set assuming the ordering in `EdgeList`.  Since this is different for the two graphs, the weights are given to different edges in the two graphs.  Also, the adjacency matrix will generally depend on the vertex ordering returned by `VertexList` (your example is a bit special because a complete graph is symmetric to the exchange of any two vertices)  Becaise of this symmetry, in your example it should be possible to permute the rows/columns of one adjacency matrix to obtain the other one.

Comment: @Szabolcs See edit please ... something nastier is going on

Comment: @Szabolcs What you are explaining is what I expected :)

Answer (score 4):

`IGUnweighted` in [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) can do this.

---

A possible implementation is

```
Graph[ VertexList[g], EdgeList[g], FilterRules[Options[g], Except[EdgeWeight]] ]
```

[However, this is not as fast as it could be.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164671/12) The current implementation IGraph/M uses is similar to how Carl Woll's [`Nucleus` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157198/12) works.

Answer (score 2):

The bug appears to have been fixed in `V13.0.0` or earlier

> [image: bugfixed]

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple loop.

Before

[image: bridge]

```
For[i = 1, i <= Length@EdgeList@bridge, i++,
  bridge = RemoveProperty[{bridge, EdgeList[bridge][[i]]}, EdgeLabels]]; 
bridge
```

After

[image: now]

Comment: This does not answer the posed question. The code does not even mention `EdgeWeight`.