# Setting $RecursionLimit crashes Mathematica 10

Tags: recursion, crash, system-variables

I have encountered what I shall presume is a bug: setting `$RecursionLimit` repeatably crashes the *Mathematica* 10 kernel:

```
$RecursionLimit = 50    (* kernel crash *)
```

Further, setting `$RecursionLimit = 20` produces a malformed Suggestions Bar containing text code starting with:

> ```
> Manipulate`Dump`eDynamicModule[ . . .
> ```

I am running version 10.0.0.0 on Windows 7.  Please report behavior on your system.

Comment: Not reproducing the crash on mac, seeing "interesting" things with the suggestions bar, though.

Comment: @rcollyer Would you try some other values, e.g. `40`?

Comment: Not a pretty result, but no crash.

Comment: I take it back. It does cause a problem, but _only_ after using a different command in other cell. Right after issuing `$RecursionLimit = 50` there is no problem as far as anything showing in console. (but the damage has allready been done internally I assume). `$RecursionLimit = 20` causes no problems.

Comment: I'll run by a couple of people internally in the morning.

Comment: I have to take back that `$RecursionLimit = 20` causes no problems also ! It does. I found out when I do the above, now code code fails with `iteration limit of 4096 exceeded.` So it looks like just setting `$RecursionLimit` causes a problem. When I start the kernel again, the same code runs ok. Only after the above setting is one, it fails.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Not reproducible on Linux with V10. But here, I just have to [wait to make the kernel crash](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54754/187) :-)

Comment: No issue for me on Mac 10.9.4

Comment: No problem on Linux V10 either, but same as @halirutan, us Linux users just need to wait :)

Comment: No issues for me with V10 on Win 8.1. However, I am seeing a different type of issue that indicate there are conflicts with other software or drivers depending on your individual PC configuration. I may try to post my specific issue later.

Comment: The issue happened both in 10.0 and 9.0.1: [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DDqi2.png).

Comment: @Silvia Shocking that this hasn't been corrected between those versions.  However have you observed any crashes?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I haven't suffered any crash from *this* issue yet, but considering I even had a crash when past a small Input cell today, I'll not surprise if one happens here..

Answer (score 6):

Not an answer but I just wanted to observe that the `$RecursionLimit` info box (whatever that is called) has a formatting error on my Mac:

[image]

*Update halirutan:* When I set `$RecursionLimit` to say 30, then hover the symbol and click on the information $i$, I sometimes get more than only wrong formatting:

[image]

Comment: heh, `"Rebranding Term"`

Comment: I see the same formatting error under Win7 x64.

Comment: Same formatting error under Linux. This is how they search and replace hahaha

Comment: This rebranding error is actually everywhere in the hover message, when originally `Mathematica` is mentioned. For example, do the same for `$Version` or `$OperatingSystem` and find a similar (slightly different) error. I think the problem is `StyleBox` support in hover message is broken.