# Kernel crash during numerical integral related to internet connection and WolframAutoUpdate

Tags: kernel, crash

I am having silent kernel crashes whenever I attempt to evaluate a difficult 2D numerical integral.  It is not consistently repeatable, in the sense that sometimes the same integral will evaluate successfully.

Reading [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54754/kernel-crash-after-idle-in-version-10-0) prompted me to try disabling the Wolfram internet connection.  When I do this the kernel still crashes but now throws this error: ""The Wolfram System cannot install paclet WolframAutoUpdate because it is currently configured not to use the Internet for paclet downloads."

What does this error message indicate?

**Added**: I am using Mathematica 10.0.1.0.  I didn't include the integral since none of this is repeatable and it seems to depend somewhat on memory load and whether there are other graphics on the screen, but here it is for grins:

```
donk1 = 617.; donk2 = 2.3*10^6; mBL = 100;

NIntegrate[
 Exp[-s^2]*s^3 (1 - Sin[donk1*s*Cqn]/(donk1*s*Cqn))*
  Cqn*(donk2*s^2*Cqn^2 + mBL^2)^-2,
 {s, 0, 3}, {Cqn, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: The message is more or less expected when there is no internet connectivity. The crash, of course, isn't. Would you mind including the integral input and which version were you using?

Comment: OK, edited.  Note that it only displays the error message right when it crashes.  I can use Mathematica and compute non-crashing integrals just fine without seeing the message.