# Cannot set VertexCoordinates twice in a Graph. Workaround?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Versions 10.0-10.2 seem to have a bug when trying to set `VertexCoordinates` twice on a graph (version 9.0 is fine).  Can you confirm it?  What is a good workaround that will not discard any other attached properties/attributes such as weights?

```
g = RandomGraph[BarabasiAlbertGraphDistribution[10, 1]]    

(* set coordinates: *)
g = SetProperty[g, VertexCoordinates -> RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]]

(* trying to change them to something else fails *) 
g = SetProperty[g, VertexCoordinates -> RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]]
```

[image]

[This related post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5618/12) describes a problem with `RemoveProperty`: I can't even remove the coordinates.

Comment: A workaround is the following: `MapIndexed[(g = 
    SetProperty[{g, First@#2}, VertexCoordinates -> #1]) &, 
 RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]]`

Comment: @PatrickStevens There are some problems with this: 1. It only works after `VertexCoordinates` has been already set once.  2. `First@#2` should be `Extract[VertexList[g], #2]&` to deal with situations where the vertex *index* does not equal the vertex *name*.  But this works: `SetProperty[g, 
 VertexCoordinates -> Thread[VertexList[g] -> RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]]]`.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I'm confused.  The documentation does seem to say *index* but for me it only works when I used the *vertex name*.

Comment: I'm out of my depth here, I'm afraid. I don't have a consistent mental model for how the `Graph` stuff works.

Comment: @PatrickStevens That's probably because the `Graph` stuff is not as consistent as the rest of Mathematica.

Answer (score 8):

A possible workaround is

```
SetProperty[g, VertexCoordinates -> Thread[VertexList[g] -> RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]]]
```

Instead of just giving a list, we must provide a list of rules assigning coordinates to each vertex name.